# I need to check the exe already installed or not before start installation using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check the exe already installed or not before start installation using c#?

In my process if the exe already installed means I should not try to install it again.

Comment: Please provide details about what you are trying to do and what is the code that you have? or the componetns that you are using. Your question is too generic.

Comment: your question should be very Clear !

Answer (score 2):

How are you installing your app? If you use ClickOnce or a .msi file, there are mechanisms to detect that the app is already installed (because the IDs match).

If you are using a custom built installer, you need to store that information somewhere, usually the registry is used (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/YourProduct is the usual place).

Answer (score 0):

When you install it write in registry in certain key a value indicating where it is installed. Next time read this registry key. If the key exist do not install it again.